# Typescript type Required for specific properties

Tags: typescript, types, required-field

Goal:

```
type Question = {
    id: string;
    answer?: string;
    thirdProp?: number;
    fourthProp?: number;
}

// usage Required<Question, 'answer' | 'thirdProp'> expect to equal
/*

type Question = {
    id: string;
    answer: string;
    thirdProp: number;
    fourthProp?: number;
}

*/
```

The above example should be pretty explanatory. I want to have type `Required` which yields the result explained above. How can one achieve that?

Comment: I believe the duplicate is the exact issue you are describing, let me know if you need any help with the answer over there :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir appreciate the well-meaning attitude